# How to define "turtle" in Python

Tags: python, pong

I put in a code that I had been using to make a "Pong" game. The code is from [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-code-pong-in-python/).

I put in

```
# Creating the Ball
ball = turtle.Turtle()
ball.shape("circle")
ball.color("white")
import turtle
```

and it said

```
NameError: name 'turtle' is not defined
```

What is wrong here, and how do I fix it?

Comment: You didn't put those lines in the same order as on the site.

Comment: The turtle module is part of the Python language, and usually does not have to be installed separately  - it may be that suppliers omit it and a separate install may be required - but even if that was the case, the OP would get an "ImportError" not a "NameError"

Comment: @Scott Actually, they did. I'm not sure why that page didn't put the import first.

Comment: Maybe the linked page is A.I. generated content - it is well written, but it have some generalisations and errors here and there that hint to it. Besides the simply not-needed and non-working "pip install turtle", for example, there is an advice to download "VS CODE from the Python site": there is no such link or relation between Python.org and vscode.

Answer (score 4):

You need to put the `import turtle` line *first* in your code.
The others should work.

Comment: Thanks, I did that but now the ball flies off the screen, through the bat and then finishes the project.